# Will a for loop that calls a function finish before any of the functions are called?

Tags: python

The following code calls a function on each loop of the `for` loop.  Is it guaranteed that the loop will finish before any of those functions are called?

```
def testFunc():
    print('this is a test')

for i in range(5):
    print('test')
    testFunc()
print("Have any test funcs been called")
```

If no, when would the `testFunc`s actually get called? (I am assuming once the function is done, if there is no multiprocessing / threading going on)

If `testFunc` has blocking code will it pause the `for` until the function has returned or is executed ?

Comment: Mmm, what the question is? You are unable to try your code in interpreter? Your function will be caled on every loop iteration as you put it inside for loop (it is indented to be part of loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the actual thing that is happening there

**Your code:**

```
def testFunc():
    print('this is a test')

for i in range(5):
    print('test')
    testFunc()
print("Have any test funcs been called")
```

**Actual Code:**

```
for i in range(5):
    print('test')
    print('this is a test')
print("Have any test funcs been called")
```

**So it is guaranteed that the loop will not finish while the functions are not completed**

**So if the function had some kind of pause function then the loop will wait till the function is finished**

**Function with wait**
    import time

```
def testFunc():
    for j in range(1,6):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("waiting for "+str(j) +" sec")
    print('this is a test')

for i in range(5):
    print('test')
    testFunc()
print("Have any test funcs been called")
```

**It actual code:**

```
import time
for i in range(5):
    print('test '+str(i))
    for j in range(1,6):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("waiting for "+str(j) +" sec")
print("Have any test funcs been called")
```

**Output:**

```
test 0
waiting for 1 sec
waiting for 2 sec
waiting for 3 sec
waiting for 4 sec
waiting for 5 sec
test 1
waiting for 1 sec
waiting for 2 sec
waiting for 3 sec
waiting for 4 sec
waiting for 5 sec
test 2
waiting for 1 sec
waiting for 2 sec
waiting for 3 sec
waiting for 4 sec
waiting for 5 sec
test 3
waiting for 1 sec
waiting for 2 sec
waiting for 3 sec
waiting for 4 sec
waiting for 5 sec
test 4
waiting for 1 sec
waiting for 2 sec
waiting for 3 sec
waiting for 4 sec
waiting for 5 sec
Have any test funcs been called
```